# Unresolved dependency after yum update crash (broken ssh connection)

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, update, dependencies

Today I was updating one of production server (one of many to test updates and then update the rest of computers).

Soon after run `yum update` ssh connection was broken :/ . After login once again using screen sesion this time I run `yum-complete-transaction` but it has problems so I run it with `--skip-broken` parameter. That worked fine for unfinished transaction but problem with perl dependency stays. I tried to reinstall perl package but it gives me an error :

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Installed package 4: perl-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64 (with updates) is not available.
Error: There is nothing to be done
```

This error I get trying to yum update:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Dependency resolution
-> Running transaction check
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.14.2-201. FC16 is updated
-> Processing Dependency: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16 for package: 1: perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-201.fc16.noarch
-> Processing Dependency: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16 for package: 4: perl-libs-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64
-> Processing Dependency: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16 for package: perl-threads-1.83-201.fc16.x86_64
---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.14.3-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-CGI.noarch 0:3.52-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-CGI.noarch 0:3.52-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-Module-Pluggable.noarch 1:3.90-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-Module-Pluggable.noarch 1:3.90-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.33-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.33-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.16-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.16-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.14.2-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.14.3-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.37-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.37-202. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-version.noarch 3:0.88-201. FC16 is updated
---> Package perl-version.noarch 3:0.88-202. FC16 is updated
-> Complete dependency resolution
Error: package: 4: perl-libs-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64 (@ updates)
          Requires: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Removing: 4: perl-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64 (@ updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Updated by: 4: perl-5.14.3-202.fc16.x86_64 (updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.3-202. FC16
          Available: 4: perl-5.14.1-188.fc16.x86_64 (fedora)
              perl = 4:5.14.1-188. FC16
Error: Package: perl-threads-1.83-201.fc16.x86_64 (@ updates)
          Requires: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Removing: 4: perl-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64 (@ updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Updated by: 4: perl-5.14.3-202.fc16.x86_64 (updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.3-202. FC16
          Available: 4: perl-5.14.1-188.fc16.x86_64 (fedora)
              perl = 4:5.14.1-188. FC16
Error: Package: 1: perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-201.fc16.noarch (@ updates)
          Requires: perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Removing: 4: perl-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64 (@ updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.2-201. FC16
          Updated by: 4: perl-5.14.3-202.fc16.x86_64 (updates)
              perl = 4:5.14.3-202. FC16
          Available: 4: perl-5.14.1-188.fc16.x86_64 (fedora)
              perl = 4:5.14.1-188. FC16
 You could try using - skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 6 pre-existing problems of the RPM database. The result of the command "yum check":
1: perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-202.fc16.noarch is a duplicate 1: perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-201.fc16.noarch
1: perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-202.fc16.noarch has missing requirements perl = ('4 ', '5 .14.3', '202. FC16 ')
4: perl-libs-5.14.3-202.fc16.x86_64 is a duplicate 4: perl-libs-5.14.2-201.fc16.x86_64
4: perl-libs-5.14.3-202.fc16.x86_64 has missing requirements perl = ('4 ', '5 .14.3', '202. FC16 ')
perl-threads-1.83-202.fc16.x86_64 is a duplicate perl-threads-1.83-201.fc16.x86_64
perl-threads-1.83-202.fc16.x86_64 has missing requirements perl = ('4 ', '5 .14.3', '202. FC16 ')
```

(this is translated to english from my native language)

How to deal with it? (next time I will use screen for update system)

My system is Fedora 16 with 3.2.3-2.fc16.x86_64 kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to resolve deps by removing perl-libs, perl-threads, perl-Pod-Escapes. Removing this apps was easy (no dependency). After that `yum update` and everything is ok even removed apps was updated (there was a problem with some kind of duplicates I think).

Lesson for me use screen :)

Answer (score 1):

Quickly run a `yum clean all`, followed by an RPM database check - `rpm --rebuilddb` - Then try again.

And you're right... Definitely use `screen` the next time you're running a critical or important system processes in the foreground on a remote session.

Comment: No that  didn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you run a `yum repolist`?

Comment: Yes I can :). Thx for your fast reaction :)